# Workaround for missing wxPython2.8 in GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debian

I run on Debian testing, and I want to use GoogleAppEngineLauncher. That demands wxPython2.8:

```
google-appengine-wx-launcher-read-only/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py
wxPython version incorrect; is 3.0, must be 2.8
```

what can i do to work around that on the GoogleAppEngineLauncher or the OS side?

Comment: There is no `Python 2.8`. The message said to install `wxPython 2.8`.

Comment: my bad. I tried to downgrade the wxPython packages to the wheezy versions, which gave me the app-engine-launcher error
    "wxPython is not available"
So instead I editied the check in google-appengine-wx-launcher-read-only/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py and changed the version check from 2,8 to 3,0 in line 28. That seemed to have done the trick.